# Question from H. Brezis, calculating dual norms

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, dual-spaces

[image]

I understand that 
$$ \|f\|_{E^*}=sup_{\|x\|_E=1}|f(x)|.
$$
I am confused about $f_i=\langle f,e_i\rangle$. Since $f\in E^*$ it is a functional $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. My best guess is since $x=x_i e_i$ we can think of $f$ as $f(x)=f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$.

Comment: In this case, you are given a linear functional $f \in E^*$ and then you define the scalars $f_i$ by setting $f_i = \langle f, e_i \rangle := f(e_i)$. This means that you can write for $x = \sum_i x_i e_i$, $f(x) = \sum_i x_i f_i$. You can also take the converse view - if you are given scalars $f_i$ then defining $f$ by $f(x) = \sum_i x_i f_i$ defines a linear functional.

Comment: What is the reason for the use of the inner product notation. I think of $\langle\, ,\,\rangle$ as a map from $E\times E$ into $\mathbb{R}$. How does this become $f(e_i)$

Comment: This is known as the duality pairing. It is fairly similar to an inner product,  (i.e. it is a bilinear form) except it lacks symmetry/conjugation as well as positive definiteness.

Comment: In the case of complete inner product spaces $E$, we have the isomorophism $E \cong E^*$

Comment: @T.Stark This notation is a common one. Some authors (maybe including Brezis) reserve $(\cdot, \cdot)$ for the inner product and don't use angled brackets. The duality pairing generalises the inner product. In the case of a Hilbert space $E$, you have the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot): E\times E \to \mathbb{R}$ and the duality pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: E^* \times E \to \mathbb{R}$. You also have an isomorphism $\phi: E^* \to E$ given by the Riesz representation theorem. (1/2)

Comment: With this set-up, $(\phi(f), x) = \langle f, x \rangle$ and so if we make the usual identification $E \cong E^*$ then the duality bracket coincides with the innner product. Hence the duality bracket is a generalisation of the inner product to e.g. general normed spaces. (2/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is
$$\|f\|=\max_i|f_i|$$
***Proof***.
Given a functional $f\in E^*$ and $x\in E$, write $x=\sum_{I=1}^nx_ie_i$, so that
$$f(x)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ie_i\right)=\sum_{I=1}^nx_if_i$$
so
$$\|f\|=\max\{|f(x)|: \|x\|_1=1\}=\max\{|\sum_{i=1}^nx_if_i|:\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|=1\}=\max_i|f_i|$$
To prove this equality, note that for every choice of $x_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|=1$, we have
$$|\sum_{i=1}^nx_if_i|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_if_i|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\cdot\max|f_i|\leq\max_i|f_i|$$
Also, given $f\neq 0$, let $j$ be an index such that $|f_j|=\max_i|f_i|$. Since $f\neq 0$, we have $f_j\neq 0$. Define a vector
$x\in E$ by $x_j=|f_j|/f_j$ and $x_i=0$ for $i\neq j$. Then $\|x\|_1=1$ and
$f(x)=|f_j|=\max_i|f_i|$, so that there is equality as claimed.

Comment: In the second equation $f(x)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_if(e_i)\right)$ should this be $f(x)=f\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i e_i \right)$

Comment: Yes, thank you.